# When is the socle small?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

I am thinking of the question  that when the (right) socle of a ring $R$ (as a right $R$-module) is small? In fact, since the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ of $R$ is the largest small right ideal, my question asks when is the socle of $R$ (the sum of all minimal right ideals of $R$) a subset of $J(R)$? Thanks in advance for any suggestion or answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you know that the Jacobson radical is the set of elements annihilating all simple right $R$-modules.

One obvious thing is that if $soc(R_R)$ is small, then $soc(R_R)^2=\{0\}$. On the other hand, the Jacobson radical contains nilpotent ideals, so the converse holds as well.

This gives a pretty simple criterion for determining if a ring has a small socle or not.

Comment: Every nilpotent ideal is contained in the Jacobson radical, so the converse does hold.

Comment: @JeremyRickard oh of course. And here I thought something interesting could happen. Adding, if you don't mind...

Comment: I don't mind at all.